# How to use FUITableViewDataSource in swift 4?

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift4

I have installed pod 'FirebaseUI'. I just want to know how to use FUITableViewDataSource in swift 4? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think it is not Swift related but new Firebase. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/197

Comment: Thanks for the valuable help. i am integrating FUITableViewDataSource in swift 4.. what should we write on number of rows in section?